# 'out' keyword in C++

Tags: c++

Is there an equivalent to the C# 'out' keyword for out parameters but in C++?

I'd like to have a constructor also set a couple of references to variables where it is called.

Comment: Do you want to just annotate your function parameters to indicate that the value will change when the function returns?  Or are you asking how to invoke a function and pass the parameter by reference(pointer) such that the function can persistently change the value the caller passed in?

Comment: What do you mean by "set a couple of references to variables"? This probably doesn't translate from C# to C++ very well.

Comment: you could probably make a similar feature yourself with a template class which could allow you to write functions like: void getValue(out<int> value); and make it throw if the value isn't set in the function.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No direct equivalent. In C++ you choose between passing by value, passing a pointer value, or passing a reference parameter. The latter two can be used to get data back from function.

```
VOID foo(int* pnA, int& nB)
{
  *pnA = 1;
  nB = 2;
}

int nA, nB;
foo(&nA, nB);
// nA == 1, nB == 2;
```

Comment: Damnit! I need to get faster! +1

Comment: (And you should prefer a reference to a pointer, as the semantics are clearer: the object must exist before --i.e. you cannot pass a null pointer)

Comment: I would argue that passing a reference in C++ is *the* equivalent to the C# `out`. Both change the semantics from call-by-value to call-by-reference. Granted the C# version is stricter about ensuring assignment inside the function... passing a pointer, however, is still call-by-value and can be emulated in C# with mutable objects (or `unsafe`).

Comment: C# requires that you prefix your out argument as `out` explicitly. It's a good thing to make a programmer 'confirm' that he is absolutely aware that this particular argument is of an `out` type. C++ assumes that programmer is aware of this king of thing, and does not require that source code is bloated by confirmations of this kind.

Comment: @pst yeah, passing a reference in C++ is more like C#'s `ref`.

Comment: @pst: It isn't. With `out`, you _initialize_ a value in some function, which is not possible in C++.

Answer (score 5):

C#'s `out` means that *initialization* of some value is done within a function. C++ does not have an equivalent.

Initialization of non-member variables is *always* done at the point of declaration, and for member variables it is done in the constructor, before the constructor body's opening brace.

Luckily, modern C++ compilers exercise [RVO (Return Value Optimization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), so const correctness usually comes at no performance penalty:

```
const Foo foo = create_a_foo();
```

A good compiler will emit something like the following p-code:

```
BYTE foo_store [sizeof (Foo)];
create_a_foo (foo_store);
const ALIAS Foo foo = foo_store;
```

Where ALIAS would just be another (typed) name for foo_store, without any runtime cost. The memory allocation for foo_store is usually free, too, as it is basically nothing else like a stack frame increment.

Even if you pass a reference to a pointer,

```
void create_a_foo (Foo* &) {...}
```

then it is not an equivalent. It is still against const-correct code, and you really are *assigning to a pointer*, which is not the same as *initializing a Foo*.

```
Foo *p;  // initialization of pointer is HERE, and nowhere else
create_a_foo(p);  // creates a Foo and _assigns_ it to po.
```

References-to-pointer are at best a hack if you intend an exact C# `out` clone, as if e.g. reference-to-`boost::optional`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the out keyword. You use pointers.

```
int x = 47;
f(&x);
//x is 5

void f(int* p)
{
  *p = 5;
}
```

See what I did there? You pass the reference of x to the function so the function actually writes a new value to x.

Comment: pointers are not the equivalent. with C#'s `out`, you _initialize_ that parameter in some function.